# Unable to Load Viwstate Error

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am having two master pages in my application and I am changing my master pages based on the drop down selection.

When i am trying to change between one master page to other I am getting

```
    HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to load viewstate. 
     The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree 
   that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  
  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a 
  post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.]
```

And I am not adding any controls dynamically too. The only diff is I hav some image controls set as runat="server" in the pages. but their Id's are same in the two master pages too

Answer (score 0):

Do a `Response.Redirect` to same page with a query string. Then in `Page_Load`, change master page based on query string.
Changing master page cannot take place in postback.

Example:

```
void uxMasterPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("MyPage.aspx?mp=2");
}

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(Request.QueryString["mp"]=="2")
  {
     //Change master page
  }
}
```

Comment: actually i implemented my change master page logic by overriding on preinit method in a class which i am inheriting for my page